# Restructure data vertically

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

There is a dataframe, example

```
df<-data.frame("x"=c(10,15,20,25),
          "y1"=c(0,1,0,1),
          "y2"=c(1,1,1,0))
```

I am trying to restructure it vertically to the form

```
df1<-data.frame("x"=c(10,10,15,15,20,20,25,25),
            "y"=c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0))
```

so that the columns y1 and y2 changes to a single column y.

I tried using the reshape package and the melt function, as follows

```
library(reshape)
df1 <- melt(df, y=c("x","y1","y2"))
```

But it fails to work and reports the following error message:

```
Using  as id variables
```

I have also followed similar problems (e.g. [How do I flip rows and columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643181/how-do-i-flip-rows-and-columns-in-r)) but these do not fit into the specifics of my problem. Any help on this is well appreciated.

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -x)`

Comment: @RonakShah thanks!  tidyr::pivot_longer reports the following error: "Error: 'pivot_longer' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tidyr'". Please, how can I fix this problem.

Comment: by installing latest version of `tidyr` or in previous version it is `gather`, `tidyr::gather(df, key, value, -x)`

Comment: @RonakShah gather works but it does not provide the output as expected. Instead of x=c(10,10,15,15,20,20,25,25) it gives x=c(10,15,20,25,10,15,20,25).

Comment: The expected output is already there you just need to sort the output. `df %>%
  gather(key, value, -x) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  arrange(x)
` is the complete code for your expected output.